# Laptop boots in Terminal mode

Tags: boot, drivers, bash, gui, bios

I've seen a couple similar posts about this problem, but none of the solutions I saw worked for me so I will try my luck here.

The problem is that after not using my laptop for something around 3 or 4 weeks, I started my laptop and it took a lot more time than usual to boot, and that is is the first moment I came accross the problem, "BIOS Error" as we can see on the screenshot below :

[image]

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.GPP4.WLAN], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/dswload2-162)
```

And then it puts me in a kind of emergency mode which represents a classic terminal ( Black screen with the white text ), asks me to login and it works, everything's still on my disk because everything displays when I "ls", but the major problem is that I think I have no more drivers. I have no wifi anymore and can't connect to any, I've tried "iwconfig" but nothing displays except "lo no wireless extensions", so I can't install anything. I've tried ctrl+alt+F7 and ctrl+alt+F1,  I've tried "startx" but none of these solutions work.

Any help is welcome, at some point if nothing works I will simply copy all my file on a USB key and install ubuntu again but I really would like to keep everything I already have installed on it !
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is an irrelevant BIOS error message from the kernel not knowing how to grok some proprietary extensions your laptop vendor installed in their implementation of ACPI. You have nothing to worry about at all, just ignore the message.

Most of the time these extensions are for things like controlling keyboard lights or other function button combinations. They don't usually work in Ubuntu anyway, so don't worry about it. (The ones that matter DO in fact work in Gnome or KDE...)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141785/discussion-on-answer-by-sean-laptop-boots-in-terminal-mode).